# How does a json formatted response from a SQL Server work?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, json

I have a stored procedure that returns query results as json and I want to understand how this query will get to my code behind in an ASP.NET app.

Stored procedure:

```
Select 
       SUBJECT AS [subject],
       STARTDATE AS [start]
       ENDDATE AS [end],
       ID AS [id]
FROM 
       SOME_TABLE
FOR JSON PATH
```

Json format from stored procedure:

```
[
 {
  "subject": _,
  "start": _,
  "end":_,
  "id":_
 },
 ...]
```

aspx.cs codebehind

*(snippet from a function)*

```
  try
        {
            if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand sccmd = new SqlCommand("MY_STORED_PROCEDURE", sqlcon);
            sccmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sccmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", valueID);
            sccmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", valueID);
            SqlDataReader sdrreader = sccmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdrreader.Read())
            {
                // lost on what to do here
            }

            sdrreader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}
        finally { sqlcon.Close(); }
```

I want to store this json response in my code behind, but I don't know how. Before making the response json I was using `SqlDataReader` with `Read()` to walk through each record, but how would this work if the response is now json; is there another class that will specifically handle a json response?

Clarification please!

Comment: Do you mean JSON is stored in SQL Server and you are retrieving that from Database via SqlDataReader?

Comment: You can use JSON.NET to cast json string to CLR object type. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have a stored procedure that returns a query in JSON format and I want to know how to get that data to my ASP.NET app. I was using SqlDataReader previously, but thats not working for me now.

Comment: Can you share the sample JSON returned by the Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Install [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) via NuGet.
2. Create a code model to mirror your json.

   ```
   public class JsonModel {  
       public int id {get;set;}  
       public DateTime start {get;set;}   
       public DateTime end {get;set;}  
       public string subject {get;set;}  
   }
   ```
3. Grab your json encoded data from the database

   ```
   string json = String.Empty;
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("... your connection string ...") {
       connection.Open();
       using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT FROM... FOR JSON PATH", connection) {
           json = command.ExecuteScalar();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Deserialize it to your model

   ```
   var JsonModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(json);
   ```
5. Drink tequila and eat fajitas!

Comment: ExecuteScalar returns only 2033 chars

Answer (score 1):

After read the SQL query return result, you can store the result into an array. Then, using json_encode function to output the result in json format.

For example,

```
int [] marks = new int[]  { 99,  98, 92, 97, 95};
var jsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = jsonSerializer.Serialize(marks);
```

Comment: This is useful, but my issue currently is that I don't know how to get my sql query return result. I tried using SqlDataReader, but that isn't working. I'll share a code snippet maybe it will help.

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal: forget the DataReader.  `var json = sccmd.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Also, you should really be using [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), not JavaScriptSerializer.